# rollback a changeset in TFS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

How do you rollback a changeset in TFS Visual Studio 2013? I see a lot of articles on '10 and '12, not 2013.

Is there a rollback button somewhere?

I've identified the changeset by right clicking on the project folder > Find > Find changesets > By user. What next? Also, when I right click a specific changeset, I get only 2 options Changeset Details... and Copy.

PS: After I successfully perform the rollback, will the changes I did (since that changeset) remain in my local copy of the project and be highlighted in Pending changes so I can check them in with a twist if I want to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find the change set you can open it and view all the files of the change in the Team Explorer window. When you have this view there is a rollback option at the top of change set details.
What this does is put the previous version of the files in your pending changes, so you can view these and compare to decide if you want to rollback all the files or just part of the change set.
Hope that helps, let me know if I you have any problems.
All the best,
John

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms194956(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, John! Yes, I have opened it and I can view all the files that are part of this changeset. Is it possible that I may not have permission to rollback? I am not seeing such option at the top of the "details for changeset # - Source file - Workspace" (title of the window). Below the title I have several buttons: Hide Comment | Change to folder view | CHange to flat view | Compare with workspace version | View file. In the left side of this window, I have: Source files | Work items | Check-in notes | Policy warnings. Nothing about "rollback" from what I see.

Comment: See if you can follow this link where it says "View details for changesets from the History window" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181408(v=vs.120).aspx you should have permission if you have contributor rights.

Comment: Thank you, John! This worked! However, the action I rolled back isn't completely erased from View history. I had deleted some files, so in my next changeset I can see them with a description "deleted; roll back" or such. Is that normal?

Comment: Hi, yes that is normal.  Rolling back the change doesn't delete the original change happening.  It keeps the original change and rolls-back all or part of a changeset as you choose.  Glad to hear you've found it.